# Custom paging in Jqgrid using WCF service and asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, wcf, jqgrid

Here is my Code for binding Jqgrid, in my scnario i am fetching 25000 records which is making grid very slow, so i need to implement custom paging in JqGrid, so that only 50 records should load at once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#TableDataGrid").jqGrid({
            url: '/DataHandler.ashx?MethodName=TFNUserView&GroupNameQuery=<%=Master.GroupName %>&isadminCheck=<%=Master.Admin %>&isActiveCheck=<%=false %>',

            datatype: "json",
            colNames: ['ID', 'TFN', 'Group', 'Sub Group', 'Tactic', 'Sub Tactic', 'Micro Tactic',
                       'Campaign Name', 'Campaign Start Date', 'Campaign End Date', 'PCC',
                       'Segmentation', 'Vanity Description', 'Message', 'Notes', 'Organization', 'Product', 'Owner', 'Agency', ],
            prmNames: { id: 'TFN' },
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: 'ID', index: 'ID', hidden: true,
                    editoptions: { disabled: true }, width: 80, "sortable": true, editable: true, sorttype: 'integer',
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq'], dataInit: function (elem) {
                            $(elem).height(21).width(40);
                        }
                    }, searchrules: { required: true }
                },
                {
                    name: 'TFN', index: 'TFN', key: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'showlink', width: 110,
                    formatoptions: { baseLinkUrl: 'TFNEdit.aspx' }, editable: true, sorttype: 'integer',
                    searchoptions: {
                        sopt: ['eq', 'ne'],
                        dataInit: function (elem) {
                            $(elem).height(21).width(60);
                        }
                    }, searchrules: { required: true }
                },
                { name: 'TeamName', index: 'TeamName', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'LanguageGroupName', index: 'LanguageGroupName', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },

                { name: 'TacticName', index: 'TacticName', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'SubtacticName', index: 'SubtacticName', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'MicrotacticName', index: 'MicrotacticName', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },

                { name: 'MarketingCampaignName', index: 'MarketingCampaignName', width: 190, editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                {
                    name: 'MarketingCampaignStartDate', index: 'MarketingCampaignStartDate', width: 190, editable: true, sorttype: 'date',
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'gt', 'lt', 'ge', 'le'] }, formatter: 'date', datefmt: 'm/d/Y', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' },
                    editoptions: {
                        size: 12, dataInit: function (elem) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(elem).datepicker({ showOn: 'button' });
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }, searchrules: { required: true }
                },
                {
                    name: 'MarketingCampaignEndDate', index: 'MarketingCampaignEndDate', width: 190, editable: true, sorttype: 'date',
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'ne', 'gt', 'lt', 'ge', 'le'] }, formatter: 'date', datefmt: 'm/d/Y', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' },
                    editoptions: {
                        size: 12, dataInit: function (elem) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(elem).datepicker({ showOn: 'button' });
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    }, searchrules: { required: true }
                },
                { name: 'PCC', index: 'PCC', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', width: 190, searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'Segmentaion', index: 'Segmentaion', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'VanityDescription', index: 'VanityDescription', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'GeneralNotes', index: 'GeneralNotes', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'Notes', index: 'Notes', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'Organization', index: 'Organization', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true }, hidden: checkAdmin() },


                { name: 'Product', index: 'Product', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true }, hidden: checkAdmin() },
                { name: 'OwnerName', index: 'OwnerName', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } },
                { name: 'Agency', index: 'Agency', editable: true, sorttype: 'text', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq', 'bw', 'bn', 'cn', 'nc', 'ew', 'en'] }, searchrules: { required: true } }



            ],
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [20, 100, 1000,10000],
            pager: $('#DivPager'),
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: true,
            sortable: true,
            width: "100%",
            autowidth: false,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            forceFit: false,
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: "TFN User View"

        });
        $("#TableDataGrid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { searchOperators: true });
        $("#TableDataGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#DivPager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, cancel: true, save: true, addtext: "Add", edittext: "Edit", deltext: "Delete", searchtext: "Search", refreshtext: "Refresh" },


        $("#TableDataGrid").setGridParam({
            onPaging: function (pgButton) {

                var pageNumber = $("#TableDataGrid").getGridParam("page");
                var lastPage = $("#TableDataGrid").getGridParam("lastpage");
                alert(pageNumber + "" + lastPage);

                //...
            }
        });
       // var requestedPage = $("#grid").getGridParam("page");
       // var lastPage = $("#grid").getGridParam("lastpage");

</script>

Here is json response  

 response = Convert.ToString(TfnUserView(groupName,isAdminCheck,isActiveCheck));
```

I am calling a WCF service here is code

```
    public string TfnUserView(string groupName, string isAdminCheck)
    {
        using (TFNEntities db = new TFNEntities())
        {
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;                
            string[] groupNames = groupName.Split(',');
            string jsonData = "";
            var query =   from st in db.TFN_Campaigns
                          join tac in db.TFN_Records on st.TFN equals tac.TFN
                          join rou in db.TFN_ROUTING_REFERENCE_VIEW on st.TFN equals rou.TOLL_FREE_NO
                          where st.Status == false && tac.IsUnable == false
                          select new
                          {
                              st.TFN,st.Language,st.TeamName,st.CreatedOn,st.Status,tac.IsUnable,rou.ROUTE_TYPE ,
                              rou.ROUTE_DESCRIPTION
                          };

            if (isAdminCheck == "True" || isAdminCheck == "true")
            {
                jsonData = serializer.Serialize(query.ToList().OrderBy(item => item.ROUTE_DESCRIPTION).Take(200254));                    
            }
            else
            {                    
                jsonData = serializer.Serialize(query.Where(item => groupNames.Contains(item.TeamName)).OrderBy(i=>i.ROUTE_DESCRIPTION).Take(25000));                 
            }

            return jsonData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I am new to Jqgrid , currently i am displaying 25000 records at once and its taking 10 sec to load , so i need to implement custom paging so that only 50 records will display at once and rest of the records on clicking next page and so on,  i have read lots blogs but could't find solution,

Comment: check out this link : http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: did not find anything in this link, try to open this link in ur system.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this link : http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager 
will help you configure paging in Jqgrid.

And then probably you can pass two more parameters to your WCF service, page and rowNum. Then use skip function along with take function in your linq like below.

jsonData = serializer.Serialize(query.ToList().OrderBy(item => item.ROUTE_DESCRIPTION).Skip(page * rowNum).Take(rowNum));

This will return specific number on records that you want to display in one page from WCF.

Comment: please guide me , how to  pass two more parameters to my WCF service,

Comment: You have to change the signture of the WCF method, public string TfnUserView(string groupName, string isAdminCheck, int rowNum, int page), and pass the same while calling the method in your code.